# Google Colab: GPU does not load with tensorflow 1.12.0

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train a model in Google Colab using the GPU

I did:

```
Edit→Notebook Settings
select GPU from the Hardware Accelerator drop-down
```

I installed this particular versions which I need for my project:

```
tensorboard==1.12.2
tensorflow==1.12.0
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.6
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.5
```

Then, when I run:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
import tensorflow as to

print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

I get:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 14765383507671724357
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 9874560735213287977
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
]

False
```

How can I use the GPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the following solves the problem:

```
!wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
!wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/libcudnn7_7.0.5.15-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb
!wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/libcudnn7-dev_7.0.5.15-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb
!wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/libnccl2_2.1.4-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb
!wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/libnccl-dev_2.1.4-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb
!wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/libcudnn7_7.1.4.18-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb

!sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
!sudo dpkg -i libcudnn7_7.0.5.15-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb
!sudo dpkg -i libcudnn7-dev_7.0.5.15-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb
!sudo dpkg -i libnccl2_2.1.4-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb
!sudo dpkg -i libnccl-dev_2.1.4-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb
!sudo apt-get update
!sudo apt-get install cuda=9.0.176-1
!sudo apt-get install libcudnn7-dev
!sudo dpkg -i libcudnn7_7.1.4.18-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb
!sudo apt-get install libnccl-dev
```